# Is it possible to change only one <img> inside the content of iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am using an iFrame to display an html file, that I don't have access to, The HTML file has a lot of image but I only want to change the first image in it. Is there any possible way to do this?

The code that I have is:

```js
iFrame.contents().find("table").width(600);
iFrame.contents().find("img").width(500);
```

the `iFrame.contents().find("img").width(500)` changes all the `<img>` in the HTML.

Comment: @Ivar Looks like jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`first` method](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to reduce the list of matched elements to the first one.

```js
iFrame.contents().find("img").first().width(500);
```